# xlutil install -Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to install xlutils package to access xls sheets in Python but unfortunately I'm unable to install it.

Python Version=3.1.1

I downloaded the tar file from this location-`http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlutils` to python31/tools/scripts directory..This is where my setup.py is located..

Then tried to unzip using 7Z file and run the setup.py install command from this directory.
and got the following..Ran the

```
C:\Python31\Tools\Scripts>setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_scripts
running install_scripts
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Python31\Lib\site-packages\UNKNOWN-0.0.0-py3.1.egg-info
Writing C:\Python31\Lib\site-packages\UNKNOWN-0.0.0-py3.1.egg-info

>>> import xlutils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import xlutils
ImportError: No module named xlutils
```

Do I need to install xlrd and xlwt before installing xlutils?

Please provide your inputs

Answer (score 0):

1. You're running `setup.py` from the wrong folder - you need to run it where you've unpacked the zip file.
2. Yes, it does need xlrd and xlwt - [See here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlutils)
3. xlrd and xlwt aren't available for Python 3 yet ([I'm working on it for xlrd](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/pull/2)).

Answer (score 0):

Today I have the same problem. You can try the below steps:

1. Install `xlrd` and `xlwt`;
2. Install [`setuptools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)
3. Install `xlutils`.

Good Luck.